# Getting raw HTTP Data (Headers, Cookies, etc) in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am wondering if it is possible to collect raw HTTP data in a Cloud Endpoint. 
I can't seem to find anything in Google's documentation, but App Engine's Twitter told me that it was (https://twitter.com/app_engine/status/305747445017624576).
If so, can I please have syntax for it?
I am aware that the API for GCE is still in its early stages, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Add an HttpServletRequest parameter to your endpoint method, e.g.

```
@ApiMethod
public MyResponse getResponse( HttpServletRequest req, @Named("infoId") String infoId ) {
    // Use 'req' as you would in a servlet, e.g.
    String ipAddress = req.getRemoteAddr();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, wow! That is surprisingly simple. Will post back with results, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I stumbled around a bit trying to figure it out (I can't remember where I found the solution) but was pleased with how simple it was when I did find it.

Comment: Probably from here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#injected_types

Comment: Is this also possible with the Python version?

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer! But where can this be found in GAE docu?

Comment: How would I do this for HttpServletResponse? (I want to serve an mp4 video through endpoint) so I need the HttpServletResponse to pass to the Blobstore api

Answer (score 0):

The request is available in an Endpoints method as an *injected type*. An object of type `HttpServletRequest` is invisibly injected into your Java method definition when you declare a parameter on the method that has that type, like this:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
...

@ApiMethod
public MyMethod getRequest( HttpServletRequest req ) {

HttpServletRequest myRequest = req;
...
}
```

This is documented here:

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/parameter-and-return-types#injected_types

Quoting from the above documentation:

> **Injected types**
>
> Injected types are those types that receive special treatment by Cloud Endpoints Frameworks. If such a type is used as a
> method parameter, it isn't made a part of the API. Instead, the
> parameter is filled in by Endpoints Frameworks.
>
> The injected types are the following:
>
> com.google.appengine.api.users.User
>
> **javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest**
>
> javax.servlet.ServletContext