# Google Cloud Endpoint Backend - Is it possible to retrieve attributes of the HttpSession?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to access the `HttpSession` object (or similar API that let me fetch session attributes) from inside of a Google Cloud Endpoints backend method...

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15871827/664577) I've learn that I can inject a `HttpRequest` object as a parameter.

What I'm trying to do is retrieve a facebook *access token* previously stored by a Servlet.

Within the Development Web Server I can retrieve the `HttpSession` and get the desired attribute:

```
@ApiMethod
public MyResponse getResponse(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String accessToken = (String) req.getSession().getAttribute("accessToken");
}
```

But, once I deploy my application to GAE, the retrieved *access token* is always null.

So is there a way to recover session attributes from inside api methods?

And if there isn't, how can I retrieve my *access token* from someplace else? Answers and comments in the [mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15522255/664577) suggests the use of the data store, but I really can't think of a good natural candidate for a key... As far as GAE authentication mechanism is concerned my users aren't even logged in, I don't know how to retrieve the `access_token` of the current user from the Datastore / memcached or any other mechanism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've filed a feature request to support sessions in production, as I can confirm it's not working right now.

For now, I recommend you continue passing the access token on subsequent requests in a header. Header information is similarly available through the injected `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the report. I'm calling the endpoints directly through client ajax requests and I don't want to share the token between the client and the server... Is there a way to inject the access_token on the header at the server side? Maybe something like a `Filter`)?

Comment: Another question... Seems like jcache (memcache) is also not working on the production server when requesting a cache entry from inside an api method (I can retrieve the same attribute through a Servlet and also through the memcache console...). Do you know if jcache was supposed to work?

Comment: So are you saying it's not possible to use sessions with google app engine endpoints? It's been a year since you filed the request, any news?

Comment: @hordurh it seems fixed now, it's added to the docs. Check this:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Enabling_sessions

Comment: @Pega88, the linked article does not talk about implementation with Cloud Endpoints (CE). The sessions already worked with Servlets but not with CE.