# Does memcache / JCache work in cloud endpoints?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, jcache

As my question title says, is Memcache supposed to play well with Google cloud endpoints?
Locally it does, I can store a key / value pair using [JCache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/usingjcache) in my application and read it from within a Google Cloud Endpoints API method.

When I upload my application and run it on the cloud it returns null exactly as the way it happens when I've found out that [we can't access sessions from inside of cloud endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19517197/664577)...

And I doing something wrong or Google cloud endpoints isn't supposed to access the cache as well?

I really need to share some tokens safely between my application and cloud endpoints and I don't want to write / read from the Datastore (those are volatile tokens...). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endpoints definitely works with memcache, using the [built-in API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/). I just tried the following trivial snippet within an API method and saw the incrementing values as expected:

```
String key = "key";
Integer cached = 0;

MemcacheService memcacheService = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
memcacheService.setErrorHandler(new StrictErrorHandler());
cached = (Integer) memcacheService.get(key);
if (cached == null) {
  memcacheService.put(key, 0);
} else {
  memcacheService.put(key, cached + 1);
}
```

This should work for you, unless you have a specific requirement for JCache.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the input. I will try it and get in touch. (I've copied your code and indeed it works, now I just need to test if I can put values in the cache using a Servlet and read them in endpoints). Any particular reason for JCache not to work?

Comment: It works fine with the low level API. Weird (but anyway, solved my problem, thanks).

Comment: Integer is trivial enough. How would you make it work with a custom object such as `Dog`