# HTPPSession with Google Cloud Endpoints new session every time

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, google-cloud-endpoints

I am successfully using Google Cloud Endpoints. Now for custom user auth, I want to use HTTPSession. The problem is, the initial session is not being reused in future calls, and new session are created (I can see from datastore admin that the session all exists, _AH_SESSION entity). As instructed in the docs, i have enabled it in appengine-web.xml:

`<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>`

I made some sample code to narrow it down:

```
@Api(name = "loginService", version = "v0.1.5")
public class LoginService {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginService.class.getName());

@ApiMethod(name = "login", path= "login")
public LoginResponse login(HttpServletRequest req)
{
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
    if(session == null){
        log.warning("creating new session");
        session = req.getSession(true);
    }

    LoginResponse resp = new LoginResponse();
    resp.statusCode = 200;
    resp.statusMessage = "SessionId:" + session.getId();

    return resp;
}


@ApiMethod(name = "show", path= "show")
public LoginResponse show(HttpServletRequest req)
{
    //session should exist when calling LOGIN first
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false); //NULLPOINTER since session from login is not being reused/found!
    LoginResponse resp = new LoginResponse();
    resp.statusCode = 200;
    resp.statusMessage = "SessionId:" + session.getId();
    return resp;
}

public class LoginResponse implements Serializable{
    public int statusCode;
    public String statusMessage;
}
```

}`

So first, I call the login method, this creates a new session and prints me the session id. Then in the next request (both using Postman - which should track sessions - in Chrome as the API explorer) i call the 'show' endpoint, and there the previous session does not exist anymore, hence the nullpointer exception.

In the comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522255/sessions-with-google-cloud-endpoints), user mikO says endpoints don't keep the session. Is this the reason? I don't really understand the reason behind it. When I just deploy a 'regular' servlet on appengine, it DOES work using Postman or just browsing.. (testing by calling the getter twice, i see that the previous session is being picked up), so it seems that the comment in that post could be right, but i really don't understand why. Working code without endpoints:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName());

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession s = request.getSession(false);
        if (s == null) {
            log.warning("creating new session");
            s = request.getSession(true);
        }

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>" + s.getId() + "</h1>");
    }
}
```

Thanks!