# Cloud Endpoints HTTP Cookies

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am implementing Cloud Endpoints with a Python app that uses custom authentication ([GAE Sessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions)) instead of Google Accounts.  I need to authenticate the requests coming from the Javascript client, so I would like to have access to the cookie information.

Reading [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056830/getting-raw-http-data-headers-cookies-etc-in-google-cloud-endpoints) leads me to believe that it is possible, but perhaps not documented.  I'm not familiar with the Java side of App Engine, so I'm not quite sure how to translate that snippet into Python. Here is an example of one of my methods:

```
class EndpointsAPI(remote.Service):
  @endpoints.method(Query_In, Donations_Out, path='get/donations',
                    http_method='GET', name='get.donations')
  def get_donations(self, req):
    #Authenticate request via cookie
```

where `Query_In` and `Donations_Out` are both ProtoRPC messages (`messages.Message`).  The parameter `req` in the function is just an instance of `Query_In` and I didn't find any properties related to HTTP data, however I could be wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, I would encourage you to try to use OAuth 2.0 from your client as is done in the Tic Tac Toe [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python).

Cookies are sent to the server in the Cookie Header and these values are typically set in the WSGI environment with the keys `'HTTP_...'` where `...` corresponds to the header name:

```
http = {key: value for key, value in os.environ.iteritems() 
        if key.lower().startswith('http')}
```

For cookies, `os.getenv('HTTP_COOKIE')` will give you the header value you seek. Unfortunately, this doesn't get passed along through Google's API Infrastructure by default.

**UPDATE**: This has been enabled for Python applications [as of version 1.8.0](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/endpoints/api_config.py?r=345#1370). To send cookies through, specify the following:

```
from google.appengine.ext.endpoints import api_config

AUTH_CONFIG = api_config.ApiAuth(allow_cookie_auth=True)

@endpoints.api(name='myapi', version='v1', auth=AUTH_CONFIG, ...)
class MyApi(remote.service):
    ...
```

This is a (not necessarily comprehensive list) of headers that make it through:

- `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`
- `HTTP_REFERER`
- `HTTP_X_APPENGINE_COUNTRY`
- `HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CITYLATLONG`
- `HTTP_ORIGIN`
- `HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET`
- `HTTP_ORIGINALMETHOD`
- `HTTP_X_APPENGINE_REGION`
- `HTTP_X_ORIGIN`
- `HTTP_X_REFERER`
- `HTTP_X_JAVASCRIPT_USER_AGENT`
- `HTTP_METHOD`
- `HTTP_HOST`
- `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE`
- `HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH`
- `HTTP_X_APPENGINE_PEER`
- `HTTP_ACCEPT`
- `HTTP_USER_AGENT`
- `HTTP_X_APPENGINE_CITY`
- `HTTP_X_CLIENTDETAILS`
- `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`

Comment: Any idea when `HTTP_COOKIE` will be enabled? I run an enterprise application and it isn't possible to use Google OAuth as it's used in the Tic Tac Toe sample.  I briefly explored setting up my own OAuth2 provider, but it seemed pretty clunky since the users would have to go through auth twice.

Anyway, the `HTTP_COOKIE` header would make life so much easier.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is a monkey patch that will work for you: http://pastebin.com/jT7T6xPS  Just make sure to replace `api_config.ApiConfigGenerator` before creating your `endpoints.api_server` for serving requests.

Comment: Thanks Danny! That worked perfectly.  I assume based on your `logging.warn` message that this will be fixed in 1.7.7, so that's awesome.

Comment: Is this really fixed in 1.7.7? The `HTTP_COOKIE` doesn't seem to be passed on .appspot.com although it works on my local dev.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @mkhatib, I'll look into it (probably after Google I/O)

Comment: It seems like passing the cookie information through doesn't work yet (context: local python environment v1.8.0)? Are you still planning to enable this? Is there a workaround we can do in the meantime?

Comment: Also will we then need to add CSRF protection manually or will there be built-in functionality through google cloud endpoints? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I'm also struggling with this. HTTP_COOKIE doesn't seem to be found in GAE but only in localhost.

Comment: It's possible this is out of date. I am no longer an employee so can't say definitively.

Comment: The post has been updated. You need to explicitly set `allow_cookie_auth` to True as in the example above for the headers + cookies to be included in appspot. It's not needed (or enabled by default) in dev_appserver.

Answer (score 10):

For the Java people who land here. You need to add the following annotation in order to use cookies in endpoints:

```
@Api(auth = @ApiAuth(allowCookieAuth = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE))
```

[source](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10100#c11)

(Without that it will work on the local dev server but not on the real GAE instance.)

Comment: This help me a lot when I am using Spring Security with Cloud Endpoints. Just adding this statement endpoints using session, where authenticated user has been set by SecurityContextPersistenceFilter