# AppEngine Endpoints HTTP Cookies

Tags: google-app-engine, http, cookies, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to read out the HTTP Cookies from AppEngine Endpoints method:

```
@ApiMethod(httpMethod = "get")
public void getAll(HttpServletRequest req) {

    log.info("req: " + req);

    Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        log.info("cookie: " + cookie.getName() + " " + cookie.getValue());
    }


}
```

But no matter what i try, the cookies are NULL. Any ideas?
It should work in this way: http://chirashi.zenconsult.net/2013/07/custom-authentication-with-google-cloud-endpoints-using-app-engine-java

Comment: If I run this application on localhost, the cookies are not deleted. It's strange...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this seems to work for me. I have tested it right on App Engine.

```
@Api(name = "api_name", version = "v1", description = "An API", auth = @ApiAuth(allowCookieAuth = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks!! This seems to have enabled sessions in my endpoints as well. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to work with Java. There's a bug filed here:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10100

With Python, cookies aren't passed through by default but [there is a way to enable them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690831/cloud-endpoints-http-cookies). I think this annotation is meant to do the same in Java but doesn't seem to do anything:

```
@ApiAuth(allowCookieAuth = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
```