# Simple Access API (Developer Key) with Google Cloud Endpoint (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there a way to use Simple Access API (Developer Key) instead of oAuth2 key with Google Cloud Endpoint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extra fields in your `protorpc` request object that aren't part of the definition are still stored with the request.

If you wanted to use a `key` field as a query parameter, you could access it via

```
request.get_unrecognized_field_info('key')
```

even if `key` is not a field in your message definition.

This is done in [`users_id_token.py`](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/endpoints/users_id_token.py?r=346#240) (the Auth part of the `endpoints` library) to allow sending `bearer_token` or `access_token` as query parameters instead of as header values.

Unfortunately, the nice quota checking and other associated pieces that a "Simple API Access" key gives are not readily available. However, you could issue your own keys and manually check a key against your list and potentially check against quotas that you have defined.

Comment: @bossylobster You know that AFAICT this is the only place on the entire interwebs that documents how to use the apiKey.

Comment: Sort of :) but this should be in the github cloud samples.

Comment: How would that work in Java? I don't see a `get_unrecognized_field_info()` or similar message there.

Comment: You would need the raw contents of the original unparsed request.

Comment: This is perfect! Now, is it possible to edit the generated API in iOS to send your additional hidden field?

Comment: By the way. don't use the actual name 'key' for the field. 'key' is a name that google reserves for the API key that you can create in the project console and you'll get an error. I just prefixed key with my project codename.

Answer (score 4):

For those looking to use @bossylobster's answer in Java, use the the SO Answer here:
[Getting raw HTTP Data (Headers, Cookies, etc) in Google Cloud Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056830/getting-raw-http-data-headers-cookies-etc-in-google-cloud-endpoints)

P.S.
I tried to make this a comment in @bossylobster's answer, but I don't have the reputation to do that. Feel free to clean up this answer so that other's can follow the path