# How to pass collection_fields from api request to @query_method decorator?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

(This is a copy of a the same question posted on [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/issues/89) about the awesome [endpoints-proto-datastore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore) library)

I am trying to implement my API so that the client can pass a '?fields=' url parameter in the api request and then I can instruct the query to build the response and return only the requested collection_fileds.

However, I don't know how to pass url parameters to the @query_method decorator; here's my code:

```
@Contact.query_method(query_fields=('limit', 'order', 'pageToken'),
                      collection_fields=('name', 'birthday'),
                      path='contacts',
                      name='contacts.list')
def contacts_list(self, query):
    return query
```

How can I pass the `fields` param from the request to the collection_fields= named param in the decorator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this is somewhat similar to [Simple Access API (Developer Key) with Google Cloud Endpoint (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748061)

In [`users_id_token.py`](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/users_id_token.py?r=410#260), the `request` object is a ProtoRPC object that parsed an incoming request. However, even if the actual user did not specify on of the keys `'bearer_token'` or `'access_token'` as part of the ProtoRPC message definition, if they were passed in the request as query parameters, they will be stored on the ProtoRPC object that is created.

To access them, the not-so-well-known method is used:

```
request.get_unrecognized_field_info(key)
```

**Why is this important?** To access `fields` on an object, let's assume the attribute `fields` was passed in through the request. Then if you have a request parsed into `my_message`, you can access the `fields` via

```
my_message.get_unrecognized_field_info('fields')
```

In [`ndb/model.py`](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/users_id_token.py?r=410#260), the `query_method` method has a locally scoped function defined there which is called `QueryFromRequestMethod`. In it, a ProtoRPC object is created directly:

```
request_entity = cls.FromMessage(request)
```

It is there where you'd want to use

```
request_entity.get_unrecognized_field_info('fields')
```

I would suggest either

1. Using a patched version of the library that only works for your use case
2. Submitting a fix to the library that allows for this customization in the method in a lightweight way
3. Subclassing `endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb.EndpointsModel` and overriding the `query_method` method to do your special bidding.

Comment: Thanks @bossylobster for the suggestions. I just noticed that only indexed properties can be projected :( this makes me re-design my query strategy and might end up doing something different. If I had to implement a solution I would go with #2.

Comment: Great! Accept answer/upvote? I recommend reading http://bjk5.com/post/54202245691/the-app-engine-way about how to optimize your applications. You can do a simple map-reduce to read all entities with a new class where the properties are properly indexed and then write the same entities back.

Comment: Great article in recommended reading! Thanks again. Accepted your answer but can't upvote due to low reputation ;) ... I'll get there!