# How do I access the user agent in Google Cloud Endpoint APIs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an api endpoint defined as follows

```
@Api (name = "auth", version = "1")
public class AuthenticationEndpoint {

    @ApiMethod 
    public AuthResult Register (@Named ("email") String email, @Named ("password") String pass) {
        // TODO: do something with the user agent here
    }    
}
```

Is there any way to access the user agent here in my Register method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a parameter of type HttpServletRequest to the method.

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056830/getting-raw-http-data-headers-cookies-etc-in-google-cloud-endpoints).