# How to obtain access to Google Cloud Endpoint's API Key in Java server code?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, access-control, api-key

Objective-C clients that are generated with [`ServiceGenerator`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios) from Google Cloud Endpoints include a field `APIKey` in `GTLService.h`:

```
// Some services require a developer key for quotas and limits.  Setting this
// will include it on all request sent to this service via a GTLQuery class.

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *APIKey;
```

How can I obtain access to the passed value in my server code (Java plus Endpoint Annotations)?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this one helps you: [Getting raw HTTP Data (Headers, Cookies, etc) in Google Cloud Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056830/getting-raw-http-data-headers-cookies-etc-in-google-cloud-endpoints)

And if you want to add some kind of security to your endpoints:

[Google Cloud Endpoints and user's authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365858/google-cloud-endpoints-and-users-authentication/25390994#25390994)

Comment: Where in the raw HTTP data would he API key show up in your opinion?