# Getting raw request body in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine

In this post I found how to get the request object: [Getting raw HTTP Data (Headers, Cookies, etc) in Google Cloud Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056830/getting-raw-http-data-headers-cookies-etc-in-google-cloud-endpoints)

Anyway, when I try to read the input stream with Commons IO, i.e. `IOUtils.toString(req.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, it's empty (no exceptions though).

Even if this makes sense to me because all data have been read at least one time by the Endpoints Fw to deserialize the bean parameter, I've thought the request object was a HttpServletRequestWrapper object with an overridden `getInputStream()` method to preserve whole data while reading many times.

Any suggestions?

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: hi! my requirement was request logging, so I implemented a filter bound to endpoints path. i.e /_ah/spi/*. To write my filter I followed this example: https://gist.github.com/calo81/2071634