# How to access Google Cloud Endpoints request header in Python and Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine-python

In the endpoints method, how to access request header information?

Answer (score 4):

Python:

In the endpoint method, `self.request_state.headers` provides this information.

```
E.g., self.request_state.headers.get('authorization')
```

Java: 
Add an HttpServletRequest (req) parameter to your endpoint method. The headers are accessible through the method getHeader()
    e.g., `req.getHeader("Authorization")`
See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056830/getting-raw-http-data-headers-cookies-etc-in-google-cloud-endpoints)

Answer (score 0):

What is working for me in python is the following:

The request I use:  http://localhost:8080/api/hello/v1/header?message=Hello World!

python code:

```
    @endpoints.api(name='hello', version='v1', base_path='/api/')
    class EchoApi(remote.Service):
        @endpoints.method(
            # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
            message_types.VoidMessage,
            # This method returns an Echo message.
            EchoResponse,
            path='header',
            http_method='GET',
            name='header')
        def header(self, request):
            header = request._Message__unrecognized_fields
            output_message = header.get(u'message', None)[0]
            return EchoResponse(message=output_message)
```