# How to get the remote ip address from google cloud endpoint?

Tags: java, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to check callers to a method in Google Cloud Endpoint against a 
whitelist. How to get the remote address of a client? (And how to get the request object?)

UPDATE: Thanks to @ikerlasaga:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "echo")
public Message echo(HttpServletRequest req, Message message, @Named("n") @Nullable Integer n) {

  String remote = req.getRemoteAddr();

  return doEcho(message, n);
}
```

Comment: This post is quite old, but I think its solution could work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056830/getting-raw-http-data-headers-cookies-etc-in-google-cloud-endpoints

Comment: I'm glad to know that it worked. However, could you post an answer instead of editing the question? that will help the community to see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this post: [Getting raw HTTP Data (Headers, Cookies, etc) in Google Cloud Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056830/getting-raw-http-data-headers-cookies-etc-in-google-cloud-endpoints)

```
@ApiMethod(name = "echo")
public Message echo(HttpServletRequest req, Message message, @Named("n") @Nullable Integer n) {

  String remote = req.getRemoteAddr();

  return doEcho(message, n);
}
```

Thanks to @ikerlasaga